# Update issue journals of redmine through Rest API

Tags: rest, redmine

I need to create new notes in existent issues of Redmine. It will be better that this can be accomplished through the Rest API, but i'm open to other solutions.

In some parts of the doc [it seems to be possible](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues#Updating-an-issue), but [in others](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_IssueJournals#Updating-an-issue) it's written *(soon)* as if it does not be implemented jet.

I [found this post](http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/16513) asking the same, but without response.

I've already try it and in the log appear:

> Processing IssuesController#update to json (for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2012-01-12 16:07:03) [PUT]   Parameters: {"format"=>"json",
>   "action"=>"update", "id"=>"8", "controller"=>"issues"} Completed in
>   34ms (View: 0, DB: 4) | 200 OK [http://localhost/issues/8.json]

But it's not really updated. I'm using this command to make the request

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:text.json" -X PUT --data "@/tmp/8.json" -u admin:admin http://localhost:3000/issues/8.json
```

and the content of 8.json is:

```
{
    "issue": {
      "subject": "subject123",
      "notes":"funciona el rest"
      }
}
```

I thing that annoys me is that i'm using port 3000 but it seems to be ignored in the log response.

Comment: Rails doesn't log the port number in its log file so don't worry about that part.

Answer (score 2):

That JSON should work. You don't want to work with the journals themselves, you want to update the issue and add a new note. That way Redmine will create the journal for you.

Is the subject getting updated? Do you have the REST API enabled? Is the admin account allowed to update that issue?

You can also try putting the notes outside of the issues object:

```
{
    "issue": {
      "subject": "subject123"
     },
     "notes":"funciona el rest"
}
```

Comment: The subject is not updated, and no note is created. I have the REST API enable. And the permissions are correct, i can update the use through the web interface. Thanks for your tips anyway.